# How to work with structs inside a library?

Tags: c

In mylib.h:

```
typedef struct {
    int len;
    unsigned char *payload;    /* payload len != len */
} packet;

packet SEND_NUMBER;
packet SEND_CHARACTER;
/* and more */
```

In mylib.c:

```
SEND_NUMBER = {
    5,
    {0x01,0x02}
}

int a_function_which_handles_packet{
}
/* and some other functions */
```

This won't work because of the error: "This declaration has no storage class or type specifier"

How can i organize my struct in a way that all (and only) library functions can access it?

Comment: If you downvote the question please give a little reason why you think it's a bad question instead of just leaving. This is (in my opinion) one of the biggest problems of this platform. Maybe I can improve my questions - but not if you don't tell me whats wrong with it.

Comment: If you only want the c file to access the struct, put the declaration in the c file

Comment: What does the code/error message have to do with your question?

Comment: @Fredrik I moved the declation to the c file which solved the "access only in library". But I still get the error. Maybe you have also an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Aggregate types, such as structs, can only be set as a whole in an initializer. Try `packet SEND_NUMBER = { ....};`

Comment: The header should declare, not define, the variables: `extern packet SEND_NUMBER:`.  Define the variables in a source file (`.c` file) using 'compound literals': `packet SEND_NUMBER = { 5, (char []){ 0x01, 0x02 } };` The header should not be published if you don't want consumers to use it — keep it private to the implementation of the library.  If you only pass pointers to structures to the functions and return pointers from the functions, then you can make the public header use an opaque structure type opaque: `typedef struct packet packet;` and fill in the details only in private code.

Answer (score -1):

Windows does this with "opaque" structures. What they're essentially doing is hiding the actual implementation details from the user. You can't really prevent someone from typecasting the actual struct and accessing its fields if they manage to reverse engineer the actual types within (via .pdb files). You could define your struct in your own library code as

```
typedef struct {
    int len;
    unsigned char *payload;    /* payload len != len */
} packet;
```

and expose header files to developers as

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t reserved[sizeof(int)+sizeof(char*)]
} packet;
```

Be careful about the padding though. You'll ensure that the structs are the same size. Check your compiler documentation to see the default padding, or just set it to 1 byte to prevent surprises.

By the way, in C11 you can do what you want using compound literals.

```
SEND_NUMBER = (packet){
    5,
    (unsigned char []){0x01,0x02}
};
```